# High Web Unload time -does it affect Time To First Byte metric?

Tags: performance, navigation, w3c, navigation-timing-api, resource-timing-api

We have a Production monitoring system which gives stats on Web Navigation and Resource Timings as indicated by W3C standards. A sample reference for stats is given below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Navigation_and_resource_timings

During production monitoring for our website, we found that Document Unload (unloadEventEnd) stats are on the higher side close to Time To First Byte (responseStart).
So, I landed up with a clarification to know:

*Whether Document Unload if it takes longer due to any possible reasons -would cause its current API/Ajax or Https request to be delayed summing up the total time took to return first byte of response and hence showing up higher value for Time To First Byte (responseStart) metric?*